# stripe webhook with firebase showing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, api, stripe-payments, webhooks

it is showing Unexpected value for STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET error even after checking it many times in the env file

the terminal shows everything created but it does not reach firebase database I am thinking there is a error in the code

the stripe dashboard also says connected

I am using the forward to local host line in git terminal

webhook code

```
import { buffer } from "micro";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

//secure a connection to Firebase from backend
const serviceAccount = require('../../../permissions.json');
const app = !admin.apps.length ? admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
}) 
  : admin.app();

// establish connection to stripe
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;
if (typeof endpointSecret !== "string") {
    console.error("Unexpected value for STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET");
    // potentially throw an error here
  }

const fulfillOrder = async (session) => {
    //console.log('Fulfilling order', session)

    return app
    .firestore()
    .collection("user")
    .doc(session.metadata.email)
    .collection("orders")
    .doc(session.id)
    .set({
        amount: session.amount_total / 100,
        amount_shipping: session.amount_total_details.amount_shipping / 100,
        images: JSON.parse(session.metadata.images),
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`success: order ${session.id} had been added to db`);
    });
};

export default async (req, res) =>{
    if(req.method === 'post'){
        const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
        const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
        const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

        let event;

        // verify that the event posted came from stripe 
        try{
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                 payload,
                 sig,
                 endpointSecret);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('ERROR', err.message)
            return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`)
        }

        //handle the checkout event 
        if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
            const session = event .data.object;

            //fulfill the order...
            return fulfillOrder(session)
            .then(() => res.status(200))
            .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`));
        }
    }
};

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
        externalResolver: true,
    },
};
```

firebase rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if false;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: file folder]

[image: console]

Comment: there is a error in firebase Firebase
'Your Cloud Firestore database is denying client requests and will continue to do so until you update your security rules' does it effect the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNNING_SECRET;

Typo: STRIPE_SIG`NN`ING_SECRET

To avoid the next issue, fix the other typo:

> const sig = req.headers["stripe-signatur"];

`stripe-signature`

Comment: i did it the error didnot come but the code didnt work meaning there was nothing onfirebase

Comment: can you help  me with that also

Comment: no error is coming but it is not working

Comment: What do you mean? Help to solve the new issue with Firebase? It's outside of the initial question. But the answer is simple: you have set "[Deny All](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#deny-all)" rule.

Comment: it didnot work.

Comment: It works as expected. You have disabled writing to your database: `allow write: if false;` That is why you got the error "Your Cloud Firestore database is denying client requests and will continue to do so until you update your security rules".

Comment: i update it but (`success: order ${session.id} had been added to db`); this line never came

Comment: or in the firebase

Comment: i tried both allow write: if false; and true

Comment: Please, create the new question with your current Firestore security rules, problematic  code snippet and exact error message. It would be nice to add `catch` block to understand  what happens with write attempts.

Comment: There is no error coming but the payment is not reaching firbase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141063/stripe-webhook-to-send-data-to-firebase-not-working/72141737?noredirect=1#comment127474887_72141737